# public Customer(int id) Gives error: Method must have return type C#

Tags: c#

At the bottom of my code, "CustomerEmail" is highlighted and says Method must have a return type.  Then "return is highlighted saying, "Since CustomerEmail(int) returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression"   I can't figure out how CustomerEmail is returning void? Am I missing something?

public class CustomerCollection
    {
        List customerList = new List();

```
    public List<Customer> CustomerList
    {
        get { return customerList; }
        set { customerList = value; }
    }

    public void RegisterCustomer(int id, string first, string last)
    {
        Customer c = new Customer(id, first, last);
        customerList.Add(c);
    }
    public void RegisterCustomer(int id, string first, string last,string phone,string email)
    {
        Customer c = new Customer(id, first, last,phone,email);
        customerList.Add(c);
    }

    public void RemoveCustomer(int id)
    {
        //works if there is a single-parameter constructor and Equals method in Faculty class
        Customer rem = new Customer(id);
        customerList.Remove(rem);
    }

  public CustomerEmail(int id)
  {
      Customer findEmail = new Customer(id);
      for (int i=0; i < customerList.Count;i++)
          if (customerList[i].Equals(findEmail))
              return customerList[i].CustomerEmail;
      return null;
  }



    public FindCustomer(int id)
    {
        Customer find = new Customer(id);
        for (int i = 0; i < customerList.Count; i++)
            if (customerList[i].Equals(find))
                return customerList[i];
       return null;

    }

}
```

Comment: Try "public string CustomerEmail"

Answer (score 0):

You must declare a return type (or `void` for methods that do not return a value).  It looks like in this case `string` is appropriate.  It's also a common convention to prefix methods that return a value with `Get` :

```
  public string GetCustomerEmail(int id)
  {
      Customer findEmail = new Customer(id);
      for (int i=0; i < customerList.Count;i++)
          if (customerList[i].Equals(findEmail))
              return customerList[i].CustomerEmail;
      return null;
  }
```

For `FindCustomer` `Customer` seems to be the appropriate return type:

```
public Customer FindCustomer(int id)
{
    Customer find = new Customer(id);
    for (int i = 0; i < customerList.Count; i++)
        if (customerList[i].Equals(find))
            return customerList[i];
   return null;

}
```

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you for clearing that up for me. I was at a dead end for awhile.

Answer (score 0):

You have no return type for the method. So your method signature is incorrect.

try and change it to

```
public string CustomerEmail(int id)
```

and

```
public Customer FindCustomer(int id)
```

However if you do not want anything to be return you need to use the `void` return type.

Have a look at the MSDN documnetion on how to create methods

[Methods (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Methods can return a value to the caller. If the return type, the type listed before the method name, is not void, the method can return the value by using the return keyword. A statement with the return keyword followed by a value that matches the return type will return that value to the method caller. The return keyword also stops the execution of the method. If the return type is void, a return statement without a value is still useful to stop the execution of the method. Without the return keyword, the method will stop executing when it reaches the end of the code block. Methods with a non-void return type are required to use the return keyword to return a value

Answer (score 0):

Change the method to

```
  public <return type> CustomerEmail(int id)
  {
      Customer findEmail = new Customer(id);
      for (int i=0; i < customerList.Count;i++)
          if (customerList[i].Equals(findEmail))
              return customerList[i].CustomerEmail;
      return null;
  }
```

Here `return type` is type of `CustomerEmail`. Same solution goes for `FindCustomer` method.